# Is it good practice to use non standard schema names in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, schema

If I have a database `MyDB`, is it considered good practice / bad practice to use schemas other than `dbo`?

For example:

```
MyDB.reports.YearlySales
MyDB.reports.TopSellers
MyDB.[data].ProviderX
MyDB.[data].ProviderY
etc
```

Comment: I've always found it odd that duplicates can have wildly different question titles. There is a definite different between 'avoiding the dbo schema' and 'using multiple schemas in a database (including dbo)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion there is nothing wrong with it. In my data warehouse I use different schemas to differentiate between data for departments or in the case that I am copying tables from a third party database, to show where those tables come from.

Comment: Your answer is best suited as comment, I am sure you would agree the *real* answer to question would include lot of pros and cons.

Comment: thanks - i agree with using it to identify data that comes from 3rd party sources. other than that, here is a good explanation